# Redirect a url to a new host

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, rewrite, url

I have the following URL which displays a normal static website: `www.example.com`. This site is hoted on Amazon.

I want to make all urls starting with `www.example.com/redirect` to redirect to another hosting account that I have. Note that I also want the host to be at the above domain (i.e., it is not a re-direct to another url here).

If this account is located at `1.23.345.678`. What do I need to change in the `.htaccess` file in order to do this redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) and [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directives.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I understand correctly, `Redirect /redirect 1.23.345.678`. How would this actually look in the .htaccess file, with tags and all?

Comment: Almost exactly as you've just done it, except it needs to be a URL - so `http://x.x.x.x/` - not just the IP. If it doesn't work right away, you might need to tweak `AllowOverride` in the Apache config.